# Stop pending intent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have one service which is running every 5 minutes

so every 5 minutes service is started and do some work and then finish and again after 5 minutes it will be started because i have set interval time of repeat to 5 minutes

Now if i want to stop that service and if i don't want to start service any more then what i have to do?

Please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perfrom [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel%28%29) on the pendingIntent.

Comment: i can not get please can you explain actually how i can get pending intent to cancel